# Expected Value to locate a country

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given 50 cards which each represent a state in the US in random order, what would be the expected number of cards you need to flip in order to locate **California**.

Hint : You need to include the flip of the card which has California.

My solution:

The expected value would be equal to the Prob(flipping the card w/ califronia) * number of cards flipped.

The expected value is given by:
$$
\frac{1}{50}* 1 + \frac{49}{50}*\frac{1}{49}* 2 + ... \frac{49}{50}*\frac{48}{49}*...*\frac{2}{3}*\frac{1}{2}49 
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{50}(1 + 2 + 3 + ... 49)
$$
which is 24.5 cards?

I don't have the answer unfortunately for this question but I was interested to see if this was the right way to go about it / if there is a more intuitive way ?

TYIA!

Comment: I think you've missed the case where the last card is California: if you still have to flip it over then the sum should go to $50$ and if not then the $49$ should have to be twice as likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is equally likely for the California card to be anywhere of the $50$ cards, hence the expected value should be

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{50} \frac{i}{50} = \frac1{50}\frac{50}{2}(1+50)=25.5
\end{align}

Remark: I assume that we have to flip the card to locate the card.